# how to management user and admin with session django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have problem in django, i have one table `User` model with table `auth_user`, this table add normal user and check exist user or no and custom login,and other URL i have admin panel i don't know how add Admin username and password, if i add admin username and password to table `auth_user` if i get session this session work for see panel users,also if user login to your panel they have `request.session` they access to panel admin with user `request.session` because admin and user use one table "Auth_User",

do you have idea for resolve?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's really not clear what you're asking here. What exactly is the problem with adding users in the admin?

Comment: ok. example: i have user login : 127.0.0.1:8000/user/login now 
i have admin login : 127.0.0.0:8000/admin/login , i create user in auth_user for user login and user logined with sessionID,for login admin i need auth_user for login?? i checked and get session this session work for both "user and admin", i need session work for user , i need session for admin ,

Comment: There is only one user model in django and only one session. A user can be admin and normal user at the same time (and therefore log into both login forms).

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to insert a user in the database directly.

Django provides the [shell command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser) to manage its users. Try `$ python manage.py createsuperuser` and follow the wizard to add a new account with admin rights to the table `auth_user`.

The reasoning behind is that `createsuperuser` takes care of the whole user creation process, which requires application logic (e.g. the password hash function).